# Instead of delete TRIGGER preventing delete on selling products

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

My problem is that I need to create a instead of delete trigger that prevents a product from being deleted if it have been sold in the past two years. Else it should be deleted a long with all order lines for the product.

My tables look something like this:

```
PRODUCT_TABLE: ID, price
ORDERITEM_TABLE: ID, Quantity, productid, ordersid
ORDERS_TABLE: ID, Orderdate
```

Its one of my first trigger so I am pretty clueless at the moment, but have an idea to do something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER productdelete
ON product
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @today datetime, @orderdate date 
SET @today = GetDate()
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT productid from product where productid = (select productid from deleted) and (SELECT orderdate from orders) > (SELECT  DATEADD(YEAR, -2, @today)))
    raiserror ('Unable to delete', 16,1)
    rollback tran
END
```

The trigger will fire on any productid that is not in the table.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Didn't you post this question earlier today? I know I saw this exact question earlier today. Your conditional logic is incorrect. It need to be comparing the OrderDate from the Order table to today's date.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an INSTEAD OF trigger, there is no need to rollback the transaction.

Simply do the DELETE in your trigger code if the conditions warrant it, and otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger runs under implicit transaction.

```
CREATE TRIGGER productdelete
ON product
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(SELECT NULL from deleted) and ..
       raiserror ('Unable to delete', 16,1)
    ELSE IF
      delete from yourtable where xx in (select yy from deleted)

END
```